# Processing: The type processing.xml.XMLElement cannot be resolved

Tags: processing

I want to set up a Projection mapper in Processing 1.5. I am following [this tutorial](http://jason-webb.info/2013/11/surfacemappergui-a-simple-processing-interface-for-projection-mapping/).

I installed every library and followed step by step but I'm seeing this error:

```
The type processing.xml.XMLElement cannot be resolved.It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.
```

Am I missing something? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're going to have to give us more specific information. Are you using the Processing editor, or are you using an IDE like eclipse? Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? How are you installing the libraries?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Hey, I am using the Processing editor. It's not that easy to provide some lines of code because I am not sure where/what the problem is. Installing the libraries: Drag downloaded library in /Documents/Processing/Library/

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to just install the library. All that does is make the library available to be added to sketches; it doesn't actually add the library to your sketch.

To add the library to your sketch, go to the menu bar Sketch -> Import Library, and then select your library.

For more info, check out [the reference](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/How-to-Install-a-Contributed-Library) on installing a contributed library.

Comment: Yes, I know. All the libs are imported